# SP cache plan not generated

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, coalesce, sqlcachedependency

There is something weird in this statement
COALESCE(@param_ids + ',', '')

@param_ids are passed in as param and it is @param_ids VARCHAR(MAX)

Any idea why the SQL-Server could not able to produce a cache plan for below scenario.
This issue has been escalted to Microsoft they are still working on it.

Not working scenario - No cache plan is generated
Step 1

Alter a SP

```
 IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@param_ids,''))) = '')  
  BEGIN  
   SELECT @param_ids = COALESCE(@param_ids + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ID)  
   FROM [dbo].Content_Type WITH (NOLOCK)  
  END
```

Step 2 
Exec Sp with params

Step 3 (No cache plan)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE [dbid] = DB_ID('databasename')
AND [objectid] = OBJECT_ID('databasename.dbo.us_spname')
GO
```

Working scenario - cache plan is generated
Step 1

Alter a SP

```
 IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@param_ids,''))) = '')  
  BEGIN  
   --SELECT @param_ids = COALESCE(@param_ids + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ID)  
   --FROM [dbo].Content_Type WITH (NOLOCK)  

    SELECT @param_ids = COALESCE('aaaaaaa' + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ID)  
    FROM [dbo].Content_Type WITH (NOLOCK)   
  END
```

Step 2 
Exec Sp with params

Step 3 (cache plan exits)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE [dbid] = DB_ID('databasename')
AND [objectid] = OBJECT_ID('databasename.dbo.us_spname')
GO
```

Thankx

Comment: While I try it on my local I get different dbID and DB_ID('databasename'). Please include DB_ID('databasename'),OBJECT_ID('databasename.dbo.us_spname') in your select statement I think they might be different for both case

Comment: Can you post the full stored procedure? I can reproduce this, but it seems if the whole procedure is within the if clause it wouldn't need to have a plan (other than return the given @param_ids) if you pass in values.

Answer (score 0):

I added a WAITFOR and I consistently get a plan. This should be independent of parameters

```
CREATE PROC dbo.testplan @param_ids varchar(max) OUTPUT
AS
IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@param_ids,''))) = '')  
  BEGIN  
   SELECT @param_ids = COALESCE(@param_ids + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ID)  
   FROM [dbo].Content_Type WITH (NOLOCK)  
  END  
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.testplan2 @param_ids varchar(max) OUTPUT
AS
IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@param_ids,''))) = '')  
  BEGIN  
   SELECT @param_ids = COALESCE(@param_ids + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ID)  
   FROM [dbo].Content_Type WITH (NOLOCK)  
  END  
GO

EXEC dbo.testplan 'bar'
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([objectid]), *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE [dbid] = DB_ID()
AND [objectid] = OBJECT_ID('testplan')
GO

EXEC dbo.testplan2 ''
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([objectid]), *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE [dbid] = DB_ID()
AND [objectid] = OBJECT_ID('testplan2')
GO
```